Event viewer showing 'logon' events, even when I'm currently using that PC
I am trying to see logon events(entering password to access PC).
However, I see many logon events in the past 1hr, even though I was using PC in the past 1hr without loggin in/out.
Why is Event Viewer showing logon events at times I didn't log in?
I followed this guide



Those are not console logon events. Most operating systems have a broader concept of 'logon' than just specifically "user taking over the physical console", and Windows is not an exception: incoming network access via SMB or SSH involves a logon, scheduled tasks that use your account involve a logon, etc.
The event's Logon Type field says 5, which means Service logon type (see values and meanings) – it's most likely associated with the starting of a "per-user" service that is tied to your session. You'll see a bunch of them in services.msc – they all have names looking like "CaptureService_2969d" with a hexadecimal session ID at the end.
Local logons would have the type 2 for Interactive.

Yep. Think "authentication" event instead of a "logon" and it makes more sense.
